# Move a heatmap colorbar on top of the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I have a basic heatmap created using the `seaborn` library, and want to move the colorbar from the default, vertical and on the right, to a horizontal one above the heatmap. How can I do this?

Here's some sample data and an example of the default:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

# Default heatma
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

[image: default heatmap]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) we find an argument `cbar_kws`. This allows to specify argument passed on to matplotlib's `fig.colorbar` method.

> `cbar_kws` : dict of key, value mappings, optional. 
>   Keyword arguments for `fig.colorbar`.

So we can use any of the possible arguments to `fig.colorbar`, providing a dictionary to `cbar_kws`.

In this case you need `location="top"` to place the colorbar on top. Because `colorbar` by default positions the colorbar using a gridspec, which then does not allow for the location to be set, we need to turn that gridspec off (`use_gridspec=False`).

```
sns.heatmap(df, cbar_kws = dict(use_gridspec=False,location="top"))
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar_kws = dict(use_gridspec=False,location="top"))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For people like me, who actually want to put the colorbar at the bottom instead of `location="top"`, add `orientation="horizontal"`

Answer (score 7):

I would like to show example with subplots which allows to control size of plot to preserve square geometry of heatmap. This example is very short:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

# Define two rows for subplots
fig, (cax, ax) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(5,5.025),  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[0.025, 1]})

# Draw heatmap
sns.heatmap(df, ax=ax, cbar=False)

# colorbar
fig.colorbar(ax.get_children()[0], cax=cax, orientation="horizontal")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to use axes divider to put colorbar on top of a seaborn figure. Look for the comments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.colorbar import colorbar

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

# Use axes divider to put cbar on top
# plot heatmap without colorbar
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar = False)
# split axes of heatmap to put colorbar
ax_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
# define size and padding of axes for colorbar
cax = ax_divider.append_axes('top', size = '5%', pad = '2%')
# make colorbar for heatmap. 
# Heatmap returns an axes obj but you need to get a mappable obj (get_children)
colorbar(ax.get_children()[0], cax = cax, orientation = 'horizontal')
# locate colorbar ticks
cax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('top')

plt.show()
```

[image]

For more info read this official example of matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_axes_divider.html?highlight=demo%20colorbar%20axes%20divider

[Heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) argument like `sns.heatmap(df, cbar_kws = {'orientation':'horizontal'})` is useless because it put colorbar on bottom position.

Comment: Concerning the last sentence here: You would need `cbar_kws = {"location":"top", "use_gridspec" : False}` as seen in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916308/4124317).