# Heatmap with multi-color y-axis and correspondend colorbar

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I want to create a heatmap with seaborn, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916205/seaborn-heatmap-move-colorbar-on-top-of-the-plot) (with the following code):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

# Default heatmap
ax = sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

I'd also like to add a new variable (lets say `new_var = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,1)), columns=["new variable"])`), such as that the values (and possibly the spine and ticks as well) of the y-axis are colored according to the new variable and a second color bar plotted in the same plot to represent the colors of the y-axis values. How can I do that?

Comment: You'd only want the ticks and the values associated with the ticks (I don't know what you mean with "spine") associated with another list of colors, is that it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses the new values to color the y-ticks and the y-tick labels and adds the associated colorbar.

[image: Heatmap with colored y-labels]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

# Default heatmap
ax = sns.heatmap(df)

new_var = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,1)), columns=["new variable"])

# Create the colorbar for y-ticks and labels
norm = plt.Normalize(new_var.min(), new_var.max())
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('turbo')

yticks_locations = ax.get_yticks()
yticks_labels = df.index.values
#hide original ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)
ax.set_yticklabels([])

for var, ytick_loc, ytick_label in zip(new_var.values, yticks_locations, yticks_labels):
    color = cmap(norm(float(var)))
    ax.annotate(ytick_label, xy=(1, ytick_loc), xycoords='data', xytext=(-0.4, ytick_loc),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color=color, lw=1), zorder=0, rotation=90, color=color)

# Add colorbar for y-tick colors
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cb = ax.figure.colorbar(sm)
# Match the seaborn style
cb.outline.set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it somehow easy to color-code also the y-axis itself?

Comment: You can add something like this in the for loop. 
`ax.annotate('', xy=(0, ytick_loc-0.5), xycoords='data', xytext=(0, ytick_loc+0.5),
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color=color, lw=1.5), zorder=1, color=color)`

Comment: How do you change the second colorbar position? For example, one on top the other on bottom sides.

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem interesting, and inspired by the unanswered comment above:

> How do you change the second colorbar position? For example, one on top the other on bottom sides. - Py-ser

I decided to spend a while doing some tests. After a little digging i find that `cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"}` is the argument for `sns.heatmap` that makes the colorbars horizontal.

Borrowing the code from the solution and making some changes, you can format your plot the way you want as in:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,5)), columns=["a","b","c","d","e"])

# Default heatmap
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar_kws={"orientation": "horizontal"}, square = False, annot = True)

new_var = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,1)), columns=["new variable"])

# Create the colorbar for y-ticks and labels
norm = plt.Normalize(new_var.min(), new_var.max())
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('turbo')

yticks_locations = ax.get_yticks()
yticks_labels = df.index.values

#hide original ticks
ax.tick_params(axis='y', left=False)
ax.set_yticklabels([])

for var, ytick_loc, ytick_label in zip(new_var.values, yticks_locations, yticks_labels):
    color = cmap(norm(float(var)))
    ax.annotate(ytick_label, xy=(1, ytick_loc), xycoords='data', xytext=(-0.4, ytick_loc),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color=color, lw=1), zorder=0, rotation=90, color=color)

# Add colorbar for y-tick colors
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
cb = ax.figure.colorbar(sm)

# Match the seaborn style
cb.outline.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Also, you will notice that I listed the values ​​related to each cell in the heatmap, but just out of curiosity to make it clearer to check that everything was working as expected.

I'm still not very happy with the shape/size of the horizontal colorbar, but I'll keep testing and update any progress by editing this answer!

==========================================

***EDIT***

just to keep track of the updates, first i tried to change just some parameters of seaborn's heatmap function but wouldn't consider this a major improvement on the task... by adding

```
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar_kws = dict(use_gridspec=True, location="top", shrink =0.6), square = True, annot = True)
```

I end up with:

[image]

I did get to separate the colormap using the matplotlib subplot routine and honestly i believe this is the right way given the parameter control that is possible to get here, by:

```
# Define two rows for subplots
fig, (cax, ax) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(5,5.025),  gridspec_kw={"height_ratios":[0.025, 1]})

# Default heatmap
ax = sns.heatmap(df, cbar=False, annot = True)
# colorbar
fig.colorbar(ax.get_children()[0], cax=cax, orientation="horizontal")
plt.show()
```

I obtained:

[image]

Which is still not the prettiest graph I've ever made, but now the position and size of the heatmap can be edited normally within the plt.subplots subroutines that give absolute control over these parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't tested your solution, but I was already able to get the colorbars as in your examples, e.g., one on the side and the other on top/bottom. What I cannot get is one on the top and the other to the bottom? As the `orientation='horizontal'` mess it up a bit.