# How to plot columns with a value and x-y positions as a color grid in subplots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

In R I would do the following to make a grid of facets with a raster-plot in each facet:

```
# R Code

DF <- data.frame(expand.grid(seq(0, 7), seq(0, 7), seq(0, 5)))
names(DF) <- c("x", "y", "z")
DF$I <- runif(nrow(DF), 0, 1)
#      x y z          I
#   1: 0 0 0 0.70252977
#   2: 1 0 0 0.74346071
#  ---                 
# 383: 6 7 5 0.93409337
# 384: 7 7 5 0.14143277
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = I)) + 
  facet_wrap(~z, ncol = 3) +
  geom_raster() + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") # desired legend position should be bottom
```

[image: ggplot + facet_wrap + geom_raster]

How can I do that in python (using matplotlib and probably seaborn)? I tried it with the following code, but had trouble with the plotting of images which I tried with `plt.imshow`. As the data has to be reshaped for `plt.imshow` I guess I need a custom plot function for `g.map`. I tried several things, but had problem with the Axes or the color and with using the data in the custom plot function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(range(8), range(8), range(6))), 
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
# order of values different than in R, but that shouldn't matter for plotting
df['I'] = np.random.rand(df.shape[0])
#      x  y  z         I
# 0    0  0  0  0.076338
# 1    0  0  1  0.148386
# 2    0  0  2  0.481053
# ..  .. .. ..       ...
# 382  7  7  4  0.144188
# 383  7  7  5  0.700624
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='z', col_wrap=2, height=4, aspect=1)
g.map(plt.imshow, color = 'I') # <- plt.imshow does not work here. 
# How can this be corrected (probably with a custom plot function)?
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The key is to reshape each group of `'z'` data with [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) into the correct format for [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html).

  - Define `vmin` and `vmax` with the `min` and `max` of the entire dataset: `vmin=df.I.min()` and `vmax=df.I.max()`
- The following code predefines the `fig` and all `axes` with `plt.subplots`.

  - [How to plot in multiple subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31726643/7758804) shows other ways to create subplots, including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75600658/7758804) creating a figure with `fig = plt.figure()` and adding subplots with `fig.add_subplot(2, 3, idx)`.
- References:

  - [One colorbar for seaborn heatmaps in subplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28356816/7758804)
  - [Move a heatmap colorbar on top of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47916308/7758804)
- **Tested in `python v3.12.0`, `pandas v2.1.2`, `matplotlib v3.8.1`, `seaborn v0.13.0`.**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(range(8), range(8), range(6))), 
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
np.random.seed(20231116)  # for reproducible data
df['I'] = np.random.rand(df.shape[0])

# create the figure and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(15, 10), sharex=True, sharey=True)

# flatten the axes into a 1d array for easy access
axes = axes.flat

# add a separate axes for the colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.3, .03, .4, .03])

# enumerate is specifically for adding the colorbar
# zip each group of 'z' data to the appropriate axes
for i, (ax, (z, data)) in enumerate(zip(axes, df.groupby('z'))):

    # pivot data into the correct shape for heatmap
    data = data.pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='I')

    # plot the heatmap
    sns.heatmap(data=data, cmap='viridis', ax=ax, cbar=i == 0, vmin=df.I.min(), vmax=df.I.max(),
                cbar_ax=None if i else cbar_ax, cbar_kws=dict(location="bottom"))

    # add a title
    ax.set(title=f'Z: {z}')

    # invert the yaxis to match the OP
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

[image]

#### `data` for `z: 5`

```
x         0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
y                                                                                
0  0.488408  0.855913  0.339374  0.452842  0.510380  0.690491  0.448773  0.500916
1  0.273653  0.561840  0.860269  0.387470  0.170281  0.718488  0.256749  0.463527
2  0.546085  0.093934  0.273339  0.503968  0.063212  0.537974  0.867814  0.135719
3  0.071505  0.792265  0.919784  0.559663  0.733996  0.032003  0.475792  0.690789
4  0.474310  0.265576  0.841875  0.496676  0.603356  0.328808  0.039460  0.461778
5  0.439142  0.119253  0.842653  0.155213  0.798092  0.093709  0.899745  0.927067
6  0.548373  0.259983  0.295939  0.700694  0.040197  0.679880  0.153048  0.328768
7  0.216977  0.176777  0.238436  0.610802  0.705161  0.614877  0.813430  0.527120
```

---

- Implementation with `plt.figure` and `fig.add_subplot`, instead of `plt.subplots`

```py
# create the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))

# add a separate axes for the colorbar
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.3, .03, .4, .03])

# enumerate is specifically for adding the colorbar and adding an axes
for i, (z, data) in enumerate(df.groupby('z')):

    # pivot data into the correct shape for heatmap
    data = data.pivot(index='y', columns='x', values='I')

    # create the axes
    ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, i+1)

    # plot the heatmap
    sns.heatmap(data=data, cmap='viridis', ax=ax, cbar=i == 0, vmin=df.I.min(), vmax=df.I.max(),
                cbar_ax=None if i else cbar_ax, cbar_kws=dict(location="bottom"))

    # add a title
    ax.set(title=f'Z: {z}')

    # invert the yaxis to match the OP
    ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: I updated matplotlib to 3.8.2 and now it works. Thank you!